# How to get contents of a file using cUrl and insert into textarea

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, curl

I'm using a form for users to fill in their username and password and a filename in order to access a specific file located on a server. The files can be accessed with a url like this:

```
http://username:password@webserver.org:8080/folder1/folder2/filename.txt
```

This would display the contents of the text file in the browser. What I need to do is to have the text content copied into a textarea I have on my site, so that users can work with the text. I would like to have users able to save the contents back to the file, but that can come later. Is there any way I can do this using Javascript or jQuery? Also, if the file is a `.html` file, I would need to have the code inserted into the textarea.

This is the form I have:

```
<form id="loginForm" action="" method="get">
        <div id="loginWindow">
            <p class="signInText">Username</p>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" required="required" />
            <p class="signInText">Password</p>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required="required" />
            <p class="signInText">File Name</p>
            <input type="text" name="filename" id="filename" required="required" />
            <input type="submit" value="Ok" id="submit" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

If this is not possible in either Javascript or jQuery, please let me know if there are any other tools or libraries I can use to achieve this.

Comment: You can have operations on Flat file like .txt, using code behind C#.net as well as XML

Answer (score 0):

> You can use [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Retrieve content using ajax and assign value to text area.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://username:password@webserver.org:8080/folder1/folder2/filename.txt",
}).done(function() {
  // Append content to text area here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use form submit method with ajax GET call and in Response you return the content 
event.preventDefault() will prevent default form submission so that you can configure your URL

```
    $("#loginForm").submit( function (event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        // make your url here 
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "url",
            success: function(response)
            {                       
                alert(JSON.stringify(response)); // see your response structure if its JSON format 
                alert(response.responseText;); // else you can get data from here 
            },
            error: function (error)
            {

            } 
        });
    });
```